# splitting a string in segments where adjacent char values differ

Tags: c#, string

This is a bit difficult for me to explain. How can I split a string where the adjacent char values in the sequence differ.

In other words...what I mean is.

if I have the following string `wwwbbddde` I want to split it so that the result is

```
www
bb
ddd
e
```

Is that possible

kind regards

Comment: Yes, that's possible. It will probably involve a loop and a result list.

Comment: What if string will be wwwbwwbddde? Expected result www b ww b ddd e?

Comment: Yes...I think I will just work it with a List and a loop...this is probably best..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ

```
string text = "wwwbbdddwwwe";
int group = 0;
string[] items = text.Select((c, i) => new { c, g = i == 0 ? 0 : c == text[i - 1] ? group : ++group })
                     .GroupBy(p => p.g)
                     .Select(p => new string(p.Select(t => t.c).ToArray()))
                     .ToArray();
```

And a bit crazy way with regex:

```
string text = "wwwbbdddwwwe";
string[] items = Regex.Matches(text, @"(.)\1*")
                      .OfType<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions:

```
        char lastChar = default(char);
        List<List<char>> result = new List<List<char>>();
        foreach (var c in inputString)
        {
            if(c != lastChar)
                result.Add(new List<char>());
            result.Last().Add(c);
            lastChar = c;
        }
        var r = result.Select(p => new string(p.ToArray())).ToList();
```